# Docker Copy Issue

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I need help figuring out why I am getting the error 'exec /usr/local/bin/run-docker-project: no such file or directory' I think is related to the copy command in my dockerfile. This has been working for the longest time and I haven't made any code changes that would cause this to break so I would like to just get some more information right now.

The project is built with a sh script that runs a docker-compose file with several services, and all of them spin up and are working except for the core project. The Dockerfile of the core project is as follows.

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:8-jre-alpine

## Update packages and install missing commands

RUN apk add --no-cache unzip dpkg curl ttf-dejavu

RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" \
    && unzip awscliv2.zip \
    && "./aws/install" \
    && rm awscliv2.zip

COPY build/distributions/docker/access-service.deb /var/access-service/access-service.deb
COPY installation/scripts/docker/run-docker-project /usr/local/bin/run-access-in-docker
RUN dpkg-deb --extract /var/access-service/access-service.deb / && \
    chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/run-docker-project && \
    /bin/rm -f /var/access-service/access-service.deb

EXPOSE 8080 5005
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/run-docker-project"]
```

The path for the run-docker-project script exists at installation/scripts/docker/run-docker-project for the Content and Repository Roots. I have the restart set to always in the docker-compose file and can get the error 'exec /usr/local/bin/run-docker-project: no such file or directory' from the restarting container. I recently updated Ubuntu. I'm not sure if that is related, but I could use some help with ideas for getting more information. Which part of the build process should I be adding the logs and what should I be adding?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and Docker 24.0.7

I tried building the project on different branches, I tried starting up a new VM, and pulling the repo fresh from the main development branch. I tried adding 'RUN ls -la' and other commands to the Dockerfile to get more information but nothing is printing out to the console (That might just be going somewhere else that I'm unaware of). I've also tried piping the output of the sh script to a text file which didn't get me any information worth mentioning.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  The two most common causes of this that I've seen are having DOS line endings (much more common on a Windows host), and the script's "shebang" line declaring `bash` on an Alpine-based image that doesn't include it (can you limit yourself to POSIX shell features, and change the "shebang" line to `sh`?).

Comment: So your suggestion to change the shebang to a sh appears to have fixed my COPY issue and it is now running the script. Unfortunately there appears to be another problem as the container is still restarting, but it appears to be a different issue so if you post your suggestion as an answer I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, the most likely issue seems to be related to the syntax of your Dockerfile. Based on your description, the problem might be with the way the ENTRYPOINT is specified.

Here's a common mistake:
`ENTRYPOINT["/usr/local/bin/run-docker-project"]`

Ensure there is a space between ENTRYPOINT and the array.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, my question didn't have a space but the actual Dockerfile does I'll edit the question to reflect that.